# Windows refuses to boot - registry issues

Tags: windows, windows-vista, boot, windows-registry, bsod

A few hours ago, my system locked up all of a sudden, so I rebooted it.

When booting, I got a screen telling me the file that the HKLM hive of my registry was located in was corrupt. I rebooted again, but I got the same error again.

I followed the screen's instructions to use my windows disk to repair, but when I tried booting from it, my PC bluescreened in relation to disk.sys

I'm at a bit of a loss here as to how this could be fixed...

I'm running 32-bit Windows Vista Ultimate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try logging in Safe Mode (boot & press F8) & make a new account (will mostly not work as HKLM is corrupted) or restore to a previous state using system restore.

If it fails, try repairing Windows again using the CD.

If it fails, I think you may need to clean install Windows again.

If you want to take a backup of your personal data present on the Windows drive (mostly C:) before you format, you can use many free tools which allow you to boot via CD ([UBCD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/download.html)) or USB([Pen drive Linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/usb-minime-2008-install-from-windows/)).

Comment: Simply logging into Safe Mode works perfectly... Odd. :S

Answer (score 0):

First try to boot using F8 to the Last Known Good Configuration.

If this doesn't work, see this Microsoft support article:
[How to recover from a corrupted registry that prevents Windows XP from starting](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307545)
As the article is about XP, better check at each step that it really applies to Vista.

Comment: The instructions looked overly complicated. But worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but this may help others.

Back up your Important data first, just in case you have a failing hard drive

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/use-ubuntu-live-cd-to-backup-files-from-your-dead-windows-computer/

Perform a chkdsk, it may be the only thing that is wrong is file corruption, which this will attempt fix.

Boot from a Vista Install disk or use F8 and choose "repair your computer" if it is available.
[image]

Use the command prompt to run a chkdsk. Once you are at the cmd line, type the line below and hit enter key, it will take some time to complete, do not interrupt the process.

chkdsk /r C:

.

How to boot into the command prompt from a Vista DVD or F8

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial147.html